# setting onClick listeners for multiple items in an array

Tags: android, dialog, onclick, selectlist, custom-lists

I am trying to implement a select list. Each item is an imageview. 

When the user clicks a view, a custom dialog opens up showing the 56 ImageViews in a list. 

The user can then click on one to select it. 

The imageviews have images named like this items_r1_c1 ... items_r56_c1.

I have to implement onClickListeners to each of the imageviews. 

 Instead I did this:

```
private int i; // This is int the outer class.
...
private ImageView [] spec = new ImageView[56];
myView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //set up dialog
                try {
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.myCustomList);
                    dialog.setTitle("Select one of 56");
                    dialog.setCancelable(true);
                    dialog.show(); 

                    String s = null;

                    //This is where I automate the ImageView object creation
                    for (i=2; i<=56; i++) {

                        s = "items_r"+Integer.toString(i)+"_c1";
                        spec[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(s,"drawable",getPackageName()));

                        spec[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                      
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                myItem.setItem(Integer.toString(i));
                                if(i == 0) myItem.setItem("invalid");
                                Log.e(tag, myItem.getItem());
                                dialog.dismiss();

                            }
                        });
                    }  
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(tag, e.toString());
                }
            }
```

However I am not getting the behavior I expected. 

What am I doing wrong? What is the efficient way of doing this instead of writing 56 onClick listeners.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters I'd put the `for( ... )` loop before the call to dialog.show().

To answer your more general question, look at the method ListView.setOnItemClickListener() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener).

You'd only have to register one listener on your ListView.  When an item in your ListView is clicked you'd end up in the code under `void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)`.  The position would be the index of the row clicked (corresponding to i in your loop).

Comment: Thank you. Will make the changes.